# close internet explorer 6 on windows ce 5.0

Tags: windows, internet-explorer-6, windows-ce

'm unable to close IE 6 in Windows CE 5.0 via the regular windows shortcuts. IE runs fullscreen and f11/alt+f4/ctrl+alt+del/alt+tab etc. do not make any difference!

Anyone?

Comment: Other applications close normally when you try ALT+F4 and other combinations?

Comment: Well... The device boots to Windows and directly autostarts IE6 in fullscreen. From there I'm unable to get any other response than clicking on a link to an url and returning to the previous page via backspace.

Comment: Are you sure that the Keyboard is functioning properly? Because, AFAIK, `Alt+F4` should work. What about `Windows+D` ?

Comment: Naturally I've tried multiple keyboards, both alt+f4 and Windows+D give no results. I've found that Escape does cancel loading of a site and ctrl+l starts the open dialog which allows browsing other url's. No shortcut has closed IE6 on Windows CE 5.0. (Have tried ctrl+alt+arrowdown as well)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of tryout (ctrl + every key, ctrl+alt+ every key) I struck gold on... Crtl+alt+end to close IE 6 in Kiosk mode on Windows CE.

Thanks for the help guys!

Answer (score 0):

1. You need some registry editor for windows CE. Maybe find one like this: [google link](https://www.google.com/?q=windows%20ce%20registry%20editor). You will need to install editor it on your PC and connect your mobile device via docking station/usb cable, IrDA whatever you have there. Mobile device must be recognized in Windows and probably synchronization software must be installed. Under Windows XP it was ActiveSync. Under 7 and newer systems I think synchronization software is built-in.
2. Go to Windows CE registry into.
3. Find `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\MICROSOFT\WINDOWS\POLICIES\EXPLORER` key and see if there is NoClose entry with value `1`. This should enable ALT+F4 key (after device reboot).

If there is no such entry under `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\...` try to find it under `HKEY_ALL_USERS\SOFTWARE\MICROSOFT\WINDOWS\POLICIES\EXPLORER`.

Comment: Hey Kamil thnx! The client is a thin client (Wyse S30), how could I connect to that? Via USB?

Comment: Hmmm I never worked with thin clients, maybe serial port? Just guessing.

Comment: There is a serial port... No clue what to do with that :D I've hooked up a mouse and key through USB and this resulted in the described issue. (I was unaware of Windows CE being for portable devices)